# How take rights from photographer to sell photos to stock photography agency

Tags: stock-photography

In my case I have hire model on internet, every is good but when I asked to sign a model release she said "me & my photographer ready are to give permission to use these photos to sell stock agency or sell those photos in any type of commercial use but her photographer is not ready to write my name in the photographer section.

Is there any model release form that doesn't content photographer name? 
Is there any other form that says this photos' rights are belonging to x photographer but x gives his rights to y photographer to sell his photos on site like Shutterstock.

Basically what I want is I want to sell his or her photos to agency like Shutterstock.

Comment: This makes very little sense? Were you or were you not the photographer? Currently it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: The English is so messed up it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like what you are saying is that you contracted with a photographer and model to shoot some stock shots for you that you want to be able to sell.  In that case, what you need is a release from the photographer.  It would still be the photographer's work, but he is yielding the right to sell it to you.  It's really unclear from the translation though.

Comment: Sounds like you need a lawyer.

Answer (score 7):

If I'm reading this correctly... a photographer produced work for you.  You wish to sell it.  The photographer is happy for you to licence it to others but is asserting their right to be identified as the creator of the work.

The photographer is the creator and copyright holder, they should be identified as such.  You should not attempt to take credit for work you did not produce.

Answer (score 0):

I will take stab at it.

As i read it you are a photographer that hired a model, this model also seems to have her own Photographer (manager?). You took the photos before getting a model release and then asked for one afterwards, the model and/or her "photog manager are not willing to sign a release.

**QUESTION: Did you know of this other photog/manager before the shoot and did you sing anything giving the model the rights to your photos**.

If you did sign anything then you own the rights  to your own work, you can not sell them if the model is not willing to sign a release and conversely the model/photog/manager also can not use or sell them. I am not a attorney nor do i play one on the internet and i am only speaking of my limited knowledge of United States laws and you will need to consult a legal advisor in your country.

I would tell her that you are the owner of the photos and you would like to sell the photos, you can propose to share a percentage of the profits or limited usage rights **IF THAT IS SOMETHING YOU ARE WILLING TO DO**, if she says no then you tell her she also has no rights to your work and that you will pursue legal action if she attempts to use them with out your permission. ( i say this because i get the sense from your post that she want to use/sell your photos.)

Do not let them intimidate you, learn your rights and assert them. Make it clear that you are not going to be pushed around and are perfectly willing to work with them if they are considerate and reasonable.

As stated by others the translation into english is very poor and confusing and i could be reading it incorrectly.

**EDIT**: *The title of your question implies that you did indeed give the rights to the photog manager or they are asserting that they do in fact own the rights*. **YOU NEED TO CLARIFY THIS TO US AND TO GET HELP IN REWRITING YOUR QUESTION IN ENGLISH.**

Comment: I found the way that I have to add photographer name along with company name in the model release form means xyz photographer / xyz company  this way it will shows that this photo is taken by xyz photographer & he or she is hired by xyz company & now I can sell that photos ( as previously mentioned photographer doesn't have any problem if I will sell those photos ) but this may be allowed in few stock photo agencies & if you are in same situation then you should consult a lawyer and see the terms and conditions of that particular stock agency.